# how to send message between two same-level component?

Tags: angular, web, components, jhipster

I have a Navbar and a Create Course page. I have two components for them: `CourseComponent` and `NavbarComponent`.

My problem is that when I enter the Create Course Page, the Navbar Component will add a button that says —— "course saving", when I click the button, it will save the course I have edited. I use the `JhiEventManager`'s `broadcast` to exchange information. here is my code:

navbar-component

```
import { JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['course.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private eventManager: JhiEventManager) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventManager.subscribe('COURSE_SAVE_EVENT', msg => {
      console.log('braodcast:  ', msg);
      if (msg.saveCourse) {
        this.saveCourse();
      }
    });
  }

  saveCourse() {
    alert('save course');
  }
}
```

navbar-component

```
import { JhiLanguageHelper } from 'app/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['navbar.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private eventManager: JhiEventManager) {}
  clickSaveCourseBtn() {
    this.eventManager.broadcast({
      name: 'COURSE_SAVE_EVENT',
      content: 'save the course',
      saveCourse: true,
      publishCourse: false
    })
  }
}
```

But!!!!!! when I enter the course page three times and click the 'save course' button, it will execute the saving operation three times! I just want it can save the data one time，what should I do?

Comment: all you need to do is to reset the page after saving the data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your subscription to the eventManager is still active when your component gets destroyed.

You can use the [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) operator from rxjs. That way, you don't have to take care of unsubscribing your subscriptions.

```
    import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

    export class CourseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

       private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

       ngOnInit() {
            this.eventManager.observable.pipe(
                takeUntil(this.destroy$))
                .subscribe('COURSE_SAVE_EVENT', msg => {
                   console.log('braodcast:  ', msg);
                   if (msg.saveCourse) {
                      this.saveCourse();
                }});
        }

        saveCourse(){
           alert('save course');
        }

        ngOnDestroy() {
           this.destroy$.next();
           this.destroy$.complete();
        }
      }
```

Comment: It reports a 'this.eventManager.pipe is not a function' error'

Comment: @Sakura_Lu which rxjs-version do you have?

Comment: @Sakura_Lu I just copied your code. It seems like you missed the name of your observable on eventManager

Comment: @Sakura_Lu looks like the actual Observable is called 'observable'. The edited answer should work.

Comment: emmm,I am not very clearly know what you means,but I can use this.eventManager.destroy() function to close the subscription ,it seems ok .

Answer (score 0):

You can use service or Input / Output Decorators to communicate between components inside app same level , parent to child and vice versa.

define your service and import it in your components .ts file then set the data you want to retrieve in other component where you will again import the service and get Data.

in 1st component :

```
this.eventManager.subscribe('COURSE_SAVE_EVENT', msg => {
      console.log('braodcast:  ', msg);
      if (msg.saveCourse) {
       this.serviceReference.setDta("courseMsg" , msg);
        this.saveCourse();
      }
    });
```

In 2nd component use this.serviceReference.getData()

and in service of course write setdata and getDta function.

2nd way Using INPUT

```
< app-messagecomponent [YourInputVariableName]= "YourMessage" >< /app-messagecomponent>
```

in app.compnent write

```
YourMessage:any='my Message to be displayed in the messageComponent';
```

in app-message.component write

```
@Input YourInputVariableName:any;
```

you can print message in `app-messagecomponent` by `this.YourInputVariableName`